# String PathParser

Tags: ruby, parsing

I'm trying to decide if I should put time into refactoring this tiny class. `PathParser` only uses string locally and every other method is used by an outside class. Should I put the small bits of logic into initialize or keep this as is?

```
class PathParser

  attr_reader :str

  def initialize(str)
    @str = str
  end

  def start_point 
    str.index('#')
  end

  def end_point
    str.rindex('#')
  end

  def row_length
    str.index("\n") + 1
  end

  def vertical_path_length
    (end_point / row_length) - (start_point / row_length)
  end
end
```

Comment: What is the intended purpose of this class? Could you update the question to include an example string and usage?

Answer (score 3):

Although I am not a Ruby guy, as a general rule of thumb I would suggest to keep it as is, since none of your accessor methods change the state of the PathParser object. The underlying string is always the same and the accessors only return relevant information based on the original state.

Essentially its a common trade off between memory and CPU, do you want to calculate everything at once and hold a bigger object in memory or you are ok with calculating on the fly and keeping a smaller object in memory. If the PathParser is initialized relatively less frequently as opposed to how often the different checks on the string are performed, then I would suggest maybe moving the calculations it in the constructor.

Hope that helps, again I come from a Java background, so my opinion might not be idiomatic to Ruby.

Comment: You can get the best of both worlds with memoization. For example `str.index('#')` would become `@start_point ||= str.index('#')`. The first time `start_point` is called it will calculate the starting point, after that it will return the cached value. This should only be used if you're worried about calculating the same value a lot, as it will consume memory.